# How to exclude files without an extension in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I know there is an easy way to do it for known extensions, adding it in excluded patterns in preferences like "*.jpg", but how can I do it for the binary files without any extension at all?

In example, my c compiled files are named with just "name", not "name.o" etc, so is there any trick to exclude them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude a file with no extension then you must manually add the exact filename for each file that you want excluded.

Using your example, to exclude a file which is called `name` then add `"name"` to your `file_exclude_patterns` list like this:

```
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", ..., "name"],
```

Since you mention `C` compiled files then to avoid having to do this regularly with all your compiled executable files you can do one of several things or some combination or variation of them.

1) Consistently use the same executable file name, for example `run`, regardless of what you are compiling.

```
gcc example.c -o run

"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", ..., "run"],
```

2) Choose a consistent prefix for the executable file names, for example `run_`.

```
gcc example.c -o run_example
gcc program.c -o run_program

"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", ..., "run_*"],
```

3) Choose a file extension for your executables and use that consistently.

```
gcc example.c -o example.out

"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", ..., "*.out"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to update an old question. As of today, we could instead specify `"file_include_patterns": ["*.*"]` in a project preference to exclude files without an extension from the sidebar.

The `"file_include_patterns"` consists of an array of glob strings, referred to by ST as file patterns. However, the file pattern of ST [only supports](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/file_patterns.html) two matching operators, `*` and `?`. According to [the document](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/projects.html), File patterns specified under  `"file_include_patterns"` are

> Patterns of files to include from the folder. Anything not matching these patterns will be excluded. This is checked before "file_exclude_patterns".

One could further set the `"index_include_patterns": ["*.*"]` to prevent ST from indexing symbols from files without an extension. Differences between `"file_include_patterns"` and `"index_exclude_patterns"` can be found in [@OdatNurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814803/odatnurd)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349294/what-is-the-difference-between-binary-file-patterns-and-index-exclude-patterns-i).

An example project configuration file `my-project.sublime-project` that prevents ST from showing files without an extension in the side bar or indexing symbols from them may look like

```json
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "file_include_patterns": ["*.*"],
            "index_include_patterns": ["*.*"],
            "path": "/path/to/your/my-project-folder"
        }
    ]
}
```

where `"/path/to/your/my-project-folder"` needs to be set accordingly.

This setting prevents ST from showing or index files without an extension under `"/path/to/your/my-project-folder"` or its sub-folders.